# Undefined arguments(Image Processing)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, arguments, double

I am having a little problem here. In the code below is a function that has two arguments when I attempt to execute the functions i obtained this error

```
 Undefined function or method  for input
arguments of type 'double' (X,CX) as shown in (1).
```

the function is coded as below

```
[CX,sse]= (vgg_kmiter(X, CX)) ....(1)
```

can someone point me out where is the problem with this code?

note that the x is the input points in a columns which is integer and the CX is the center of clustering which is also integer.

Thank you

Comment: Far too little information is provided about how you call the function and how it is defined. And your question has NOTHING to do with image processing. This is a basic problem in your understanding of the language and how to use it.

Comment: [CX', sse] = vgg_kmiter(X, CX)
  X is DxN matrix of N D-dim points, stored in columns
  CX is DxM matrix of M cluster centres
  out: CX' is DxM matrix of new cluster centres
sse is sum of squared distances to (old?) cluster centres

Comment: Again, the meaning of these arrays is irrelevant. Cluster centers or whatever. You are giving us far more information that is not pertinent, yet still not telling us what is important. How is the function defined? Is it an m-file? Is it on your search path?

Answer (score 1):

`[CX,sse]= (vgg_kmiter(X, CX)) ....(1)`

Is not a valid line of code.

`[CX,sse]= (vgg_kmiter(X, CX));`

is fine, though the outer parentheses aren't needed.

`[CX,sse]= (vgg_kmiter(X, CX)) %....(1)`

is fine as well - everything after the `%` sign is considered a comment